# error CreateProcess error=193, %1 no es una aplicacion Win32 valida en Android Dtudio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

En Android Studio, al crear un nuevo proyecto, se activa el gradle, y luego de unos segundos aparece el siguiente mensaje:

> error CreateProcess error=193, %1 no es una aplicacion Win32 valida

He buscado informacion para tratar de solucionarlo, pero no encuentro la manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es importante agregues más datos como el sistema operativo en donde tienes Android Studio. Esto sucede si un archivo .exe es corrupto o simplemente no es adecuado para la versión de Windows, agrega esa info Checluy! :)

Answer (score 1):

En mi caso fue un problema con la ruta del JDK.

Yo solamente puse la ruta adecuada del JDK para Android Studio 2.3.3

File -> Project Structure -> En el panel de la derecha "SDK Location" -> JDK Location -> Click en los 3 puntitos "..." para seleccionar la ruta del JDK
que por defecto debes tenerlo instalado en "C:\Archivos de programa\Java\" y seleccionas la carpeta que empiece con "jdk*" en mi caso fue "jdk1.8.0_131" y listo aceptas